# JsonResponse not working properly

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to read the below json response

```
{
"title": "Flipkart Affiliate API Directory",
"description": "This directory contains information about all the affiliate       API's and their versions",
"apiGroups": {
"affiliate": {
    "name": "affiliate",
    "apiListings": {
        "bags_wallets_belts": {
            "availableVariants": {
                "v0.1.0": {
                    "resourceName": "bags_wallets_belts",
                    "get": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/feeds/youraffiliateid/category/v1:reh.json?expiresAt=1420910131274&sig=7db02590dfaea9a22f88c869d8035d05",
                    "post": null,
                    "put": null,
                    "delete": null
                }
            },
            "apiName": "bags_wallets_belts"
        },
        "washing_machine": {
            "availableVariants": {
                "v0.1.0": {
                    "resourceName": "washing_machine",
                    "get": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/feeds/youraffiliateid/category/v1:j9e-abm-8qx.json?expiresAt=1420910131275&sig=7c48abab9d35ae77fff3d998e1a2efdc",
                    "post": null,
                    "put": null,
                    "delete": null
                }
            },
            "apiName": "washing_machine"
        },
    }
 }
}
```

I need an array of "apiNames". Below is my class on how I am trying to read the json

```
class SearchProducts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    final List<RowItem> rowItem = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    final int SUCCESS = 0;
    final int FAILURE = SUCCESS + 1;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(FlipkartProducts.this, "", getString(R.string.searchingflipkart));
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            String urlString = "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/api/royarnab8.json";
            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            String response = streamToString(inputStream);
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("apiGroups");
            int a = jsonArray.length();
            Log.d("The length of the array is", "" + a);

            for (int i =0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject mainImageJsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("affiliate")
                        .getJSONObject("apiListings");
                String categories = mainImageJsonObject.getString("apiName");

                RowItem ri = new RowItem(categories);
                rowItem.add(ri);

            }
            return SUCCESS;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return FAILURE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (result == SUCCESS) {
            lv.setAdapter(new SavedUrlAdapter(FlipkartProducts.this,rowItem));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(FlipkartProducts.this, getString(R.string.errorfk), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
public static String streamToString(InputStream p_is)
{
    try
    {
        BufferedReader m_br;
        StringBuffer m_outString = new StringBuffer();
        m_br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p_is));
        String m_read = m_br.readLine();
        while(m_read != null)
        {
            m_outString.append(m_read);
            m_read =m_br.readLine();
        }
        return m_outString.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception p_ex)
    {
        p_ex.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

After running the program, I am getting the jsonArray "apiGroups". But after that, nothing happens. Can anyone please help me solve this?

Comment: "apiGroups" is not a JSONArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONObject groupObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("apiGroups");

String apiName =groupObject.getJSONObject("affiliate").getJSONObject("apiListings").getJSONObject("bags_wallets_belts").getString("apiName");
```

To be more specific for all objects under apiListings:

```
JSONObject apiListingObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("apiGroups").getJSONObject("affiliate").getJSONObject("apiListings");
JSONObject obj4=null;
       //Getting all the keys inside json object with key- pages
          Iterator<String> keys= apiListingObject.keys();
          while (keys.hasNext()) 
         {
               String keyValue = (String)keys.next();
               obj4 = apiListingObject.getJSONObject(keyValue);
               //getting string values with keys- apiName
               String pageid = obj4.getString("apiName");           
         }
```

Comment: what does obj3 signify?

Comment: obj3 changes after every iteration, on first iteration obj3 will be JSONObject with key bags_wallets_belts and on second iteration obj3 will be JSONObject with key washing_machine

Comment: I have used this but it is showing "org.json.JSONException: No value for bags_wallets_belts". The code is exactly same, but just before Iterator, I wrote "JSONObject obj3=apiListingObject.getJSONObject("bags_wallets_belts");" line of code to define obj3

Comment: oh my bad replace obj3 with apiListingObject, edited my answer